# Notification logo not shown when app not running (FCM)

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, sharedpreferences

So i have implemented FCM for notifications. 
So, we can also send some data along with an notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging.
Here i have created a channel and registed the device to a "general" topic.

Here is my code :

package com.femindharamshi.fcmtrial;

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Map m = remoteMessage.getData();
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), m);

        Class me = remoteMessage.getClass();
        Log.d("MessageDateRecieved", ""+me.toString());

    }

    public void showNotification(String title, String message, Map m) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotifications")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_logo)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(message);

        NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        manager.notify(999, builder.build());

    }
}
```

Now i am having following 2 issues :

1. When the app is not running/killed, then the notification logo (R.drawable.small_logo) residing in my res/drawable folder is not shown instead a gray circle is shown. How do i solve this problem.
2. If i pass data through this message i can capture it in a Map. Now imaging the app is not running and i want to save this data in SharedPreferences, then how is it possible ?

Comment: The grey Icon is shown due to the shape of your icon. Try using an icon with a different shape and it will work. And regarding saving the data when the notification is clicked the values which were sent with it will be passed to your launcher activity as intent and you can extract them using `getextra`

Comment: Your service is not called if the app is not running hence you cannot create a custom notification.

Answer (score 0):

Icon shown for notification when your app is not running can only be monochrome, so icon with transparency should be used as a shape and color for it can be provided separately. It looks like these lines inside `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/icon_notification_shape" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/color_notification" />
```

Comment: Awesome! so by doing this, i can get notifications with my logo even when the app is not running ? and the colour i am providing can be anything ?

Comment: Yes, you will get custom monochrome logo for notifications when your app is not running. It will use default color in status bar, but when you expand notifications logo will be colored as you provided.